# Возможно ли создать атрибут экземпляра в классе

Tags: python

Не используя конструктор `__init__`?

То есть существует ли вариант объявления (инициализации переменных), которые будут полями экземпляра не используя конструктор?

Answer (score 1):

```
class A:
    b = 1

def c(self, z):
    print(self)
    return z

a = A()
print(a.b)

A.c = c
print(a.c(2))

a.d = c
print(a.d(a, 3))

a.e = 4
print(a.e)


class D(dict):
    pass

d = D(name='my_name', num=3)
print(d)
```

Answer (score 1):

Есть несколько вариантов.
Во всех примерах ниже я буду показывать, как объекту класса назначить поле "x", равное 1.

Первый: Объявить "голый" экземпляр класса, и уже готовому экземпляру руками выставить нужные атрибуты.

```
class A:
    pass

a = A()
a.x = 1
```

Второй: Использовать специальный метод new.

```
class A:

  def __new__(cls):
    obj = super(A, cls).__new__(cls)
    obj.x = 1
    return obj
```

Третий: написать метод-инициализатор, и запускать его либо руками после создания экземпляра, либо автоматически из new.

```
class A:

  def my_init(self):
    self.x = 1


a = A()
a.my_init()
```

Это только то, что навскидку в голову приходит. Подозреваю, тут можно ещё подобных вариантов придумать.

Но правильный способ, всё-таки - использовать init.